# Running JMeter from a configurable JAR

Tags: java, junit, jmeter, integration-testing, performance-testing

I'd like to have a `myapp-tester.jar` that can be ran from a developer's machine, or as part of a CI build. It's purpose would be to test `myapp.war`. I would like to use JMeter as the basis for the test harness.

I see that it is (somehow) possible to write JUnit tests that launch JMeter. I'm wondering if its possible to package this code in an executable JAR and then run it from the command line?

That way, I could make the URL injectable as a System property and test the same app on different environments:

```
java -jar myapp-tester.jar -Durl="http://devmyapp01.example.com"
java -jar myapp-tester.jar -Durl="http://qamyapp01.example.com"
```

etc. If this is possible, how might I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JMeter test can be launched from Java code and there are 2 options:

1. Run existing .jmx file
2. Create performance test using JMeter's API on the fly.

See [5 Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](http://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) chapter 4. Running A JMeter Test Through a Program (from Java code) for all necessary details.

JMeter "understands" global system properties so passing URL of the application under test via Java system property can be done.